# Scaling values in R data frame by group and variable name

Tags: r, apply, multiplication

I have a large set of scaling factors I wish to apply to a data frame, these factors are particular to the group a sample comes from and particular to each variable of the sample. I have tried to construct a minimal example for this question.

SCALING FACTORS

```
Batch A     B
Q     1.01  1.31
R     0.90  1.22
S     1.04  1.09
```

DATA

```
Batch A     B
Q     23    10
Q     22    11
R     27    12
R     26    13
S     22    14
S     24    15
```

so then, say, batch Q sample 1 would go from 23, 10 to 23.23, 13.1

I realise that there could be an apply somewhere in the solution to this but I am struggling to work out where to start. Any help much appreciated :-)

```
scaling_factors_example<-data.frame(Batch=c("Q","R","S"),A=c(1.01,0.9, 1.04), B=c(1.31, 1.22, 1.09))

data_example<-data.frame(Batch=c("Q","Q","R","R","S","S"), A=c(23,22,27,26,22,24), B=c(10,11,12,13,14,15))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A riff on Mark's answer (borrowing his abbreviations), except it uses `match` instead of merge as that is often much faster for N-1 joins:

```
d[, -1] <- d[, -1] * s[match(d[, 1], s[, 1]), -1]
```

which produces

```
#   Batch     A     B
# 1     Q 23.23 13.10
# 2     Q 22.22 14.41
# 3     R 24.30 14.64
# 4     R 23.40 15.86
# 5     S 22.88 15.26
# 6     S 24.96 16.35
```

`match` finds the position of a value in the first vector, in the second vector, which effectively allows to do N-1 merges as is the case here.  And as I noted, it's faster, which may matter if you have large tables you're joining:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(s[match(d[, 1], s[, 1]), -1])

# Unit: microseconds
#     min      lq   median      uq     max neval
# 167.854 173.706 176.6315 181.019 279.025   100

microbenchmark(merge(d[ ,1, drop=F], s, "Batch"))

# Unit: microseconds
#     min       lq   median       uq      max neval
# 983.353 1060.149 1068.195 1103.302 2181.004   100
```

Side note, if you have large tables, you should consider `data.table` for merges, as that can be even faster than `match`, under some circumstances.

Answer (score 5):

Its easier if you go the merge way instead of using the apply family, I think (`s` is `scaling_factors_example`, `d` is `data_example`)

```
m <- merge(d[ ,1, drop=F], s, "Batch")
d[-1] <- m[-1] * d[-1]
d

  Batch     A     B
1     Q 23.23 13.10
2     Q 22.22 14.41
3     R 24.30 14.64
4     R 23.40 15.86
5     S 22.88 15.26
6     S 24.96 16.35
```

**Explanation**

`merge` gives you a dataframe of the same size as your data containing the corresponding scaling factors for each entry. Now you can simply multiply the columns.

Comment: Thank you for your swift and helpful reply: drop=F and the merge function are very handy tips; however, I accepted BrodieG's answer as I think speed may be important in my application.